# Getting a setting, the chdir value, out of GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen, bash-scripting, working-directory

I've been using `screen`'s `chdir` command to set a new working directory for new screen windows, more on that later. What I need to do is find out what the setting was before I set it, so that I can set it back. I can do this experimentally by starting a new session and echoing out `$PWD` but I can't seem to do this more concretely in a way that I can grab and store the value in a script. I feel like there's probably some command in the very detailed man page that will accomplish this, but I haven't found it yet.

Now to explain what I'm doing specifically that calls for this:
I have a script that starts up about 4 processes in parallel, it turns out to be very handy to have them each start in their own `screen` window. In the bash script it's easy to determine I'm running the script within `screen` with this test: `if [[ $TERM =~ screen* ]]; then` there's other ways, but this one is fine. In the script I can then execute `screen -x -X screen process1`. This attaches to the current session in multiuser mode and asks it to open a new `screen` window running the process. It's necessary from within the script, because without -x it'll complain that the current command isn't run in a terminal, which is about right, it's not interactive. Anyway, the process1 needs to run in a particular path. Not just one, but one of any four or five where different versions of process1 are. I'm running the script from that path. But `screen` often isn't started from that path, so process1 will start in a new working directory set to wherever `screen` was started. No problem though, just execute `screen -x -X chdir $PWD` before starting process1 (2, 3, and 4) and you're now in the right path. However you've permanently changed `screen`'s default working path for a new window, this will upset the user (me, and some colleagues). So it should be no problem to issue `screen -x -X chdir $oldCHDIR` before exiting. However, I can't seem to find out what `$oldCHDIR` was, and frankly it could be anything, nothing so simple as it definitely being `$HOME`. If you're still reading and wondering what my question was, it was the one in the first paragraph, how can I find out `screen`'s current `chdir` setting.

Comment: Why not start a subshell before changing?

Comment: Starting a subshell would let you change the directory in the subshell and leave screen alone.

Comment: So I'd call: `screen -x -X screen bash -c 'cd '$PWD';process1'`. That'd work. It's a workaround to finding out the `chdir` setting, which I feel like should be possible somewhere.

Comment: Of course now no one will answer the actual question. This is why you should never explain yourself. I don't really want to JUST solve this ONE problem. I want to know, as a question, can I get a setting like what `chdir` is set to out of `screen`. The answer can be yes, here's how or no. All too often I'm getting these: why not do something totally different. That's fine when there's a great reason to. But in this case it slows down the startup to each process and it uses more memory.